# Can I use a dynamic variable in a BarcodeURL function?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am having an issue with the following code:

```
<img style="width: 400px; height: 200px" title=barcode border=0 hspace=0 alt=barcode 
     src='%%=BarCodeURL("%%=v(@TransactionID)=%%","Code128B", 400, 200, 0)=%%' 
     width=400 height=200>
```

I am trying to create a barcode based on the transaction ID that is passed in the email, but whenever I use the `@TransactionID` variable the barcode does not appear.  If I put in a static value it works, but that is not what I need.  Any suggestions?

Comment: welcomt to sfse Ryan. To format code or make html characters visible you can use the {} button in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the v() operator, nor the 2nd %%= call within the tag.  Try the following:

```
<img style="width: 400px; height: 200px" title=barcode border=0 hspace=0 alt=barcode 
     src='%%=BarCodeURL(@TransactionID,"Code128B", 400, 200, 0)=%%' 
     width=400 height=200>
```

Hope this helps!